# How to run `show` and `animate` at the same time with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I know this might be duplicate, but I tried different ways and still didn't find the right solution!

How can I make the button move up slowly after the page load?
And why when I add this to my `js` file the function won't work? But it will works inside the html `<script>` tag, and I'm sure my `js` is linked to my html correctly.

here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#back__button").delay(3000).show("slow").animate({
    bottom: '20px',
    opacity: '1'
  }, 1500).addClass("jumping__btn");
});



/* $(document).ready(function() {

$('#back__button').css({'display':'block', 'opacity':'0'}).animate({'opacity':'1','bottom':'20px'}, 1500);
}); */
```

```css
.back__button {
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -70px;
}

.back__button a {
  color: #ffe9c6;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.back__button,
#home__button {
  transition: 200ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.back__button a:hover {
  color: #C89822;
}
```

```html
<div class="back__button" id="back__button">
  <a href="portfolio.html" class="scroll active">
    <svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
    <br />Back</a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing jQuery animations and CSS transitions. Remove the CSS transition:

```
.back__button,
#home__button {
  transition: 200ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

and your jQuery animate works as expected:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#back__button").delay(3000).show("slow").animate({
    bottom: '20px',
    opacity: '1'
  }, 1500).addClass("jumping__btn");
});
```

```css
.back__button {
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -70px;
}

.back__button a {
  color: #ffe9c6;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*
.back__button,
#home__button {
  transition: 200ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
*/
.back__button a:hover {
  color: #C89822;
}
```

```html
<div class="back__button" id="back__button">
  <a href="portfolio.html" class="scroll active">
    <svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
    <br />Back</a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```